# Why is the first character count is not getting printed for the below .py file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Fetching of the occurrence count of each individual unique character. Still it's doing fine without any error but it's not printing the count on the first character(**s**) present in the string "**str**".

```
import string
str="sdffDFREWFSDFWSSSSDWEWSWQDDddcdcdd"
j=0
exists=[]

#Iterated throughout the sting object

for i in range(len(str)):

   for j in range(i):
      if str[i]==str[j]:
         continue
      elif str[i] not in exists:
         print (" %c exists %d times" %(str[i],str.count(str[i])))
         exists.append(str[i])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core problem is that you're using a nested loop where it is not necessary, and the first run of that second loop is skipped entirely, because `for j in range(i):` does no iterations if i is zero. The simplest correction to your approach would be something like

```
str ="sdffDFREWFSDFWSSSSDWEWSWQDDddcdcdd"

exists=[]

for i in range(len(str)):
    if str[i] not in exists:
        print (" %c exists %d times" %(str[i],str.count(str[i])))
        exists.append(str[i])
```

A more pythonic version would be something like

```
myStr = "sdffDFREWFSDFWSSSSDWEWSWQDDddcdcdd"
seen = set()
for letter in myStr:
    if letter not in seen:
        seen.add(letter)
        print(" %c exists %d times"%(letter, myStr.count(letter)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply iterate through the string character by character and count the characters with a `dict`:

```
str="sdffDFREWFSDFWSSSSDWEWSWQDDddcdcdd"
character_occurence = dict()
for char in str:
  character_occurence[char] = character_occurence.get(char,0) + 1
```

Now `character_occurence` contains the number of occurences of each character in your string. Calling `character_occurence["s"]` will return the number of `s` characters in your string.

Comment: Try it with collections.defaultdict: `d = collections.defaultdict(int)`; and in the loop, `d[char] += 1`. also check out `collections.Counter`.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit* [Better Solution Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48195564/7538507)

```
str="sdffDFREWFSDFWSSSSDWEWSWQDDddcdcdd"
exists=[]

   #Iterated throughout the sting object

for i in range(len(str)):
    for j in range(len(str)):
        if str[i]==str[j]:
            continue
        elif str[i] not in exists:
            print (" %c exists %d times" %(str[i],str.count(str[i])))
            exists.append(str[i])
```

This is a working solution in my 3.x version of python. The initial j value was not needed and I converted the second range check to also use the length of the string object.